# Making Windows text larger (easier to read) without getting text cropped off

Tags: display, font-faces

I have old tired eyes and a super hi res screen and want to make text larger. I've already increased the Font DPI, but if I make it too big then text gets cut off in some programs.

I'm *hoping* that choosing a font family that renders larger, but I see no way to do that.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: What Version of windows? Scaling works differently between them.

Comment: Would the magnifier be a solution to your problem?  Or at least a temporary fix?